# Помогите сократить код питон

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Заменить все числа, меньшие последнего элемента массива, на 1.

```py
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

if m[0] < m[-1]:
    m[0] = 1
if m[1] < m[-1]:
    m[1] = 1
if m[2] < m[-1]:
    m[2] = 1
if m[3] < m[-1]:
    m [3] = 1
if m[4] < m[-1]:
    m[4] = 1
if m[5] < m[-1]:
    m[5] = 1
if m[6] < m[-1]:
    m[6] = 1
if m[7] < m[-1]:
    m[7] = 1
if m[8] < m[-1]:
    m[8] = 1
if m[9] < m[-1]:
    m[9] = 1
print(m)
```

Comment: почитайте о цикле for, будет полегче

Comment: @СергейШ, `[:-1]` лишнее, съедает последний элемент

Comment: m = [1 if x < m[-1] else x for x in m]

Answer (score 2):

Решается через цикл `for`:

```py
m=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(len(m)-1):
    if m[i] < m[-1]:
        m[i] = 1
```

Либо использовать генератор списков:

```py
m=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

res = [1 if x < m[-1] else x for x in m]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш подход хороший, но — как вы правильно предполагаете — код практически *тот же самый для всякого элемента.*

Например, здесь ваши команды `if`:

```
if m[0] < m[-1]:
if m[1] < m[-1]:
if m[2] < m[-1]:
    ...
if m[9] < m[-1]:
```

Правые стороны сравнивания все идентичны, а в левых только меняется число от 0 до 9.

Назовем это число `i` и для себя запишем всех 9 команд `if` в сокращенной форме, как в математике:

- ```
      if m[i] < m [-1]:    (для i = 0, 1, 2, ..., 9)
  ```

То же самое с командами после команд `if`, и мы добавим их в нашу сокращенную форму в виде тоже только одной команды с переменной `i`:

- ```
      if m[i] < m [-1]:    (для i = 0, 1, 2, ..., 9)
          m[i] = 1
  ```

Но чтобы ясно было, что заметка

- ```
         (для i = 0, 1, 2, ..., 9)
  ```

касается теперь **обеих** команд, поместим ее вверх и обе команды отступим:

- ```
  для i = 0, 1, 2, ..., 9:
      if m[i] < m [-1]: 
          m[i] = 1
  ```

Остается только записать эту заметку в соответствии с правилами Питона:

- ```
  for i in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9:
      if m[i] < m [-1]: 
          m[i] = 1
  ```

---

*Замечания:*

1. В Питоне, к сожалению, невозможно пользоваться тремя точками как в математике, но существует другой механизм:

   - **диапазон**, по-английски `range`.

   В скобках за функцией `range()` задается первое число диапазона, и затем первое число **за** диапазоном, т.е. то, которое в него **уже не входит**:

   ```
   for i in range(0, 10):
   ```

   Даже возможно первое число пропустить, когда оно равно 0:

   ```
   for i in range(10):
   ```
2. Программисты не любят [**«магические» числа**](https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/magic-numbers), как например 10. Теперь ваш список имеет 10 чисел, но что в случае, когда их будет скажем 32?

   Для числа элементов в списке существует функция `len()` (из английского length, длина), мы можем применить ее к нашему списку `m` чтобы магическое число 10 заменить на `len(m)`:

   ```
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i] < m [-1]: 
            m[i] = 1
   ```
3. Наш путь к улучшению вашей программы в определенном смысле парадоксальный:

   - Ваш оригинальны код понимают (почти) все.
   - Код с `for i in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9:` большой прыжок, но все равно еще понятный.
   - Код c `for i in range(0, 10):` уже может ввести в заблуждение.
   - Код c `for i in range(10):` уже почти непонятный.
   - Но и `for i in range(len(m)):` понимает только тот, который сам так делает.

   Вопрос тогда в том, где остановиться...
   Или для кого пишете вашу программу.
   Потому что **программы пишутся для людей**, а не для компьютеров.

Comment: ещё стоит добавить что последовательность вида `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n - 1` можно задать с помощью `range`

Comment: @Danis, да, всегда чего добавлять, проблема только в том, когда остановиться. :-)